# How to build 643 rooms in Fallout shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

How to build 643 rooms in Fallout shelter?
I filled all the space and I build just 129 rooms?

**EDIT:**

I see 643 score for section Rooms in Global Ranking

Comment: You can have multiple vaults right? Are you sure it's not 643 rooms across many vaults?

Comment: 10x, @Robotnik. Now it seems more logical :).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get 643 rooms in fallout shelter, I don't know where you got this number. According to the wiki the actual maximum amount is lower, much lower

[Source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_rooms)

> There are 25 floors; all floors can hold eight rooms. In addition all floors can hold up to two elevators. Adding more than two elevators per floor will sacrifice space for other rooms.

so 25*8=200 rooms

Comment: Ok, then it is build + destroyed, because if you go to global scoring there was people with 643 in sections rooms.May be they build only elevators?!?

Comment: Like said by @Robotnik , it might be that they have multiple vaults. That it takes that in to account. Maybe just elevators. That is also a possibility. Can't really say as i need to see the vaults. A third option is that they are hacking. But I doubt it.

Comment: Its also possible that "score" is not the same as "count". eg you might get more points for the higher level rooms than the lower level ones.